# Solve $X_2$ given $A(X_1;X_2)=B$

Tags: systems-of-equations

Given that

1. $A$ is a $n \times n$ random orthogonal matrix, such that $A^TA=I$, $A^T1_n=1_n$, where $1_n$ is the vector of ones of size $n$.
2. $X = (X_1;X_2)$ is an $n \times p$ matrix with full column rank.
3. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $\frac{n}{2} \times p$ matrices.
4. $A$, $X_2$ are unknown, while $X_1$ and $B$ are known.

Can we solve $X_2$ given $A(X_1;X_2) = B$?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you mean by $A^T1_n=1_n$? Is $1_n=I$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What are your thoughts on this? You'll find that questions here receive a lot more positive attention and attract more helpful answers if make an effort to show some understanding of the problem and/or an attempt to solve it.

Comment: @Fakemistake, sorry for the confusion, I was thinking of matrix with full column rank.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, $1_n$ is the vector of ones.

Comment: Since $X$ has full column rank, $p \le n$.  But how is $p$ related to $n/2$?  Certainly if $p=1$ and $n$ is large you shouldn't expect to determine $X_2$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, thanks for your thoughts. What if $p=\frac{n}{2}$?

Comment: An orthogonal matrix preserves the Euclidean norm of vectors, so a necessary condition for a solution to exist is that the norm of each column of $X_1$ is at most the norm of the corresponding column of $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example in the case $n=4$, $p=2$.

$$ X_1 = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr}, B = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \cr 0 & 1\cr 1 & 2\cr 3 & 4\cr} $$
Among the possibilities are

$$  A = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
                 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr
                 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr
                 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr},\ X_2 = \pmatrix{1 & 2\cr 3 & 4\cr} $$
and
$$A = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
                 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr
                 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr
                 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr},\ X_2 = \pmatrix{3 & 4\cr 1 & 2\cr} $$

So no, you can't solve for $X_2$.